# Anti Capture ( Detect record screen)

Tags: video, capture

I have an educational videos for sale...
now i protect educational videos , but hacker is can buy it then playing and record from screen!
are you have a solution for **detecting** capture?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you could do that, there wouldn't be so many illegal streaming/download/torrent websites on the internet...